# uma das operações VS uma operação

Tags: gramática, concordância

Na seguinte frase:

Realizei uma operação duas vezes

> Gostaria de saber qual é procedimento para cancelar **uma das operações** ?

**ou**

> Gostaria de saber qual é procedimento para cancelar **uma operação**?

Gostaria de saber qual das frases está correta ou se ambas são validas?

Comment: no meu entendimento, as duas estão corretas. No caso do 1o exemplo, já se sabe que houve 2 operações...no segundo caso, não se sabe se houve 1, 2 ou mais operações.

Comment: Gostaria de saber como você acha que uma delas seria inválida?

Comment: A primeira indica que você deseja cancelar **apenas** uma operação, sem cancelar. Enquanto que na segunda você deseja cancelar operação(ões) em geral, seja uma, duas, ou três; deseja saber como se cancela um objeto da natureza de uma operação.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Gostaria de saber qual é procedimento para cancelar **uma das operações** ?
>
> 2) Gostaria de saber qual é procedimento para cancelar **uma operação**?

Ambas estão corretas, mas não são equivalentes.

A opção (1) é mais exata, específica para a situação de duas operações terem sido realizadas e se desejar cancelar apenas uma delas. Nesse sentido ela é preferível.

A frase (2) é muito mais genérica: isso significa que uma resposta completa poderia ter que ser consideravelmente extensa, caso existam várias situações possíveis e procedimentos diferentes para cada uma delas (em particular, ela incluiria a resposta à pergunta (1)). Mas o risco é a resposta dada ser simplificada e/ou assumir uma certa situação - não necessariamente a relevante.